# Phone shows up as null in Android Studio

Tags: windows-7, android, android-studio

I'm trying to run my app on Android from Android Studio. It's just an empty activity for now. Just to note, I already ran apps in the past using USB debugging and it has worked just fine without me having to tinker with anything.

The problem is that my phone gets recognized correctly the first second I plug it in, but after that it's as if it disconnects and shows up again as "2b54deb59804 [null]".

Tried with another phone (Xiaomi Redmi 6) and it got recognized correctly. Same drivers were used as well, which means it's an issue with my Xiaomi Redmi Note 4.

I tried turning off USB debugging and turning it back on again, as well as restarting my phone, but it made no difference. Tried with setting it in file transfer mode as well, same thing happens. Shows up correctly at first and then goes to null.

Running adb devices command I get:

```
adb server is out of date.  killing...
* daemon started successfully * 
List of devices attached 
2b54deb59804    connecting
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works fine with a third USB cable on a different USB port so I suppose that was an issue.

Comment: *What* was an issue?